# Saving a path object between states (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am working on a sketchpad android application. I am using a path object to draw the users input, but am having trouble retaining it. Right now whenever you navigate away from the page everything that the user draws is erased. What is the best way to retain the path object so that I can redraw the users previous input when states are changed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to declare the `Path` object using `static` keyword and as class variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, didnt even think of that. Works perfectly!